# Table of definitions formatting help

Tags: tables

I'm using the following code to produce a table of definitions.

```
\begin{tabular}{rl}
$R$ is... & ...if and only if... \\
\hline
irreflexive & for all $x$ iht $xx \notin R$. \\
\hline
transitive & for all $xyo$ iht if $xo \in R$ and $oy \in R$, then $xy \in R$. \\
\hline
antisymmetric & for all $xy$ iht if $xy \in R$ and $yx \in R$, then $x=y$. \\
\hline
a partial order & $R$ is transitive and antisymmetric. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}`
```

To be honest, the final output looks pretty mediocre. Any ideas for how to improve it?

EDIT: Here's a complete file, featuring a second attempt at the table. Neither are very satisfactory, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\begin{defi} Fix arbitrary $R$. Then ($R$ is a \textit{relation}) if and only if ($R$ is a set, and every element of $R$ is an ordered pair). Supposing $R$ is indeed a relation, then the following hold.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|rl|}
\hline
$R$ is... & ...if and only if... \\
\hline
irreflexive & for all $x$ iht $xx \notin R$. \\
\hline
transitive & for all $xyo$ iht if $xo \in R$ and $oy \in R$, then $xy \in R$. \\
\hline
antisymmetric & for all $xy$ iht if $xy \in R$ and $yx \in R$, then $x=y$. \\
\hline
a partial order & $R$ is transitive and antisymmetric. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? How would you like it to look?

Comment: Using a `definition` environment seems appropriate for a "list of definitions".

Comment: @IanThompson I don't know! Professional, I guess. I tried getting rid of some of the lines to make it look easier on the eye, but I doubt whether I've succeeded. EDIT: I guess I want the top line to look sort of like a title, or heading, if that makes sense.

Comment: This is a bit subjective; it's difficult to help without knowing exactly what you want. I suggest looking in a few books to find a style you want to use. Then post a picture here if you can't get TeX to reproduce it.

Comment: Okay, good thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems rahter subjective, but here is my take on it.

I'd say use less lines and if so use different lines, for example using the `booktabs` package with `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`. Also you can introduce a definitionsymbol; as notation is somewhat unregular use whatever is familiar to you. In the following I'll use `:\Leftrightarrow` .

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l c p{.5\textwidth}}
\toprule
$R$ is...       &                  & ...if and only if... \\
\midrule
irreflexive     &$:\Leftrightarrow$& for all $x$ iht $xx \notin R$. \\
transitive      &$:\Leftrightarrow$& for all $xyo$ iht if $xo \in R$ and $oy \in R$, then $xy \in R$. \\
antisymmetric   &$:\Leftrightarrow$& for all $xy$ iht if $xy \in R$ and $yx \in R$, then $x=y$. \\
a partial order &$:\Leftrightarrow$& $R$ is transitive and antisymmetric. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll tinker with the code a bit and we'll see what happens.